# Using Drupal and Ruby. Has anyone integrated both?

Tags: ruby, drupal

I started a small web project and used Drupal to build it. So far, so good: you can quickly set up a nice CMS oriented site, add social features via modules, and you have an extensive API to do the customizations in a nicely architected platform.

The problem comes now: the site is growing beyond what was originally planned for and I find myself in the situation of seriously starting write code for it. While I gained a new respect for PHP thanks to the Drupal project, I want to do it in Ruby. I'll feel more confortable, it'll be easier to maintain later and I can reuse it in other Ruby/Rails apps. Over time I suppose I'll rewrite the existing parts in Drupal in Ruby.

Based on this, the question is: has anyone integrated both (both a success or failure story)? It's quite a big decision, and I just can't find info about anyone who has done it on Google.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry to be negative. This doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

> I'll feel more confortable, it'll be easier to maintain later for me and I can reuse it in other Ruby/Rails apps.

I seriously doubt that. It will probably be more difficult to maintain/reuse in the future because of the extra code you will need to write to "integrate" Drupal and Ruby. The more the code, the more the likelihood of bugs. I'm assuming you're going to link the two together using REST/webservices/similar technology -- if that is the case you are writing so much extra code! Gluing the front end elements (which have to be in Drupal) with the functional elements (probably in Ruby) justs sounds so complicated to me.

I'm guessing its only you who is going to be maintaining the code. What if its someone else? Will you easily be able to find someone who has two skill sets (Ruby + Drupal) in your area/budget?

What about giving back to the Drupal community? If your code becomes something useful and its this big mess of Drupal + Ruby you really can't put it up on Drupal.org for others to build, improve and test.

I suggest two options

1. Use Drupal only.
2. Sounds like you're in love with Ruby or at any rate just too used to it. In that case: Find a Ruby based CMS! (Sorry I don't know any!)

To me its a classic dilemma: Should you do Drupal Custom Module development which will mean more short term pain cause you'll be out of your comfort zone.... or should you integrate Ruby + Drupal which will be easier in the short run but very painful in the long.

I would choose short term pain :-)

Comment: BTW some Ruby based CMSes (haven't worked with either) http://refinerycms.com/ http://radiantcms.org/

Answer (score 3):

I think the term used to describe your idea is Polyglot Programming:  http://memeagora.blogspot.com/2006/12/polyglot-programming.html

One of my criticisms of Drupal is that everything is in Drupal or PHP. Drush is an exception of course but it would be nice to see some development tools that don't use the Drupal stack exclusively. I have used Apache Ant on Drupal with some success (before the days of Drush).

I've also worked on a Drupal project that provided Software as a Service to a Java front end. That didn't work too well but the Drupal Services project has enjoyed some renewed development since then. I've also worked on several Drupal projects that interface with flash front ends (ugg!), google maps and mobile phone gadgets.

Are you thinking of a Service Orientated Architecture? If you're comfortable with that then you could be on the write track to writing truly agile software. I'd like to hear how you go!

However, if your only justification is that your feel more comfortable in Ruby (and I can see why) then, you should probably get yourself out of your comfort zone.